# Including QueryClientProvider from react-query package is not working

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I am a beginner to react-query. I was trying to add QueryClientProvider from 'react-query' to my react project. I used npm install react-query to install the react query and then I included QueryClientProvider outside  component in index.js. This is what i have done so far:

```
    **index.js**  
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
    import './index.css';
    import App from './App';
    import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
    import {  QueryClient, QueryClientProvider} from 'react-query';
    
    const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
    
    const queryClient = new QueryClient() ;
    
    root.render(
        <React.StrictMode>
          <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
            <App />
          </QueryClientProvider>
        </React.StrictMode>
    );
    reportWebVitals();
```

But when I go to localhost:3000, it shows blank screen. On checking the console it shows the following error:

**Console**

```
    Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
    1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
    2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
    3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
    See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
    
     Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useEffect')
        at Object.useEffect (react.development.js:1632:1)
        at QueryClientProvider (QueryClientProvider.js:36:1)
        at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16175:1)
        at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20913:1)
        at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:22416:1)
        at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4161:1)
        at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4210:1)
        at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4274:1)
        at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27405:1)
        at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26513:1)
```

What is possibly wrong here? I have tried searching for the error but couldn't find any relevant resource.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, please include code snippets in the question itself rather than adding links to images. More information about formatting is available here: [How do I format my code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: @Abir Taheer Thanks for pointing out. I have updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I tried to reproduce your example and I didn't run into any problem...

I would start looking for the problem with the following steps:

- check if the Query Сlient was initialized correctly;
- check npm package versions, clean npm cache, cleanly reinstall dependencies (deleting lock file);
- try to get rid of extraneous factors in order to localize the problem.

Next, I attach a link to an example of using react-query:

[Code Sandbox link >](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-bardeen-d9iw4v)

P.S. It would be great if you could add the error message and minimal code to reproduce in the description of the problem.

Comment: Thanks @bhoodream. I have checked by creating a new create react app project and then npm install react-query in other PC as well. There also I am getting the same error. To check the syntax errors, I have used the exact same code provided as sandbox link above, but still it gives me the same error. I have also tried deleting package-lock.json and then doing npm install but still no luck. I believe there might be some bug in the recent version.

Comment: Try to search or (if not there) create this issue in the github repo of react and react-query, maybe someone has already encountered this, or the contributors will tell you where to dig.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve it? I'm facing the same problem